# Razor page with inline Model gets compiled at runtime on first request?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

If we use inline Model in an asp.net core razor page, does the page gets compiled on first request and gets loaded into memory or it has be re-compiled on each request?

Just asking this question to get an idea whether there will be an effect on performance with in-line models vs compiled models.

Answer (score 0):

Razor pages are not recompiled on each request. Razor Pages view files (`.cshtml` files) are compiled on first request only, when you may experience a lag in the time it takes to get the content. You can choose to precompile the `.cshtml` files by adding the following to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```